# UISearchBar barColor not matching UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uicolor

I am setting the `barColor` of my UISearchBar to the same color that my navigation bar is set to. When I get back the results in the UI the colors do not match. I have translucent set to YES for both the searchbar and the navigation bar.

[image]
[image]

Can anyone tell me how I can get the color of the searchbar to match the nav bars color?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way I have found to accomplish this is by using an image instead of just a color.

```
[mySearchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor blackColor] forBarPosition:UIBarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

`imageWithColor:` is a category method I wrote on `UIImage` that looks like this:

```
+ (UIImage *) imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Doing this, I am able to get the `UISearchBar` background to match the `UINavigationBar` background exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the `backgroundColor` of the `UISearchBar` to `UIColor.clearColor()`. Then the `barTintColor` will come through as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I answered another SO question that is very similar to this one. Just setting `translucent` to `NO` won't do the trick. You have to slightly alter your color you use for the `UISearchBar` when you set it for the `UINavigationBar`. [Check out my full answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41928652/3911918).