# Color in storyboard not matching UIColor

Tags: ios, colors, interface-builder, uistoryboard, uicolor

I am defining a color in code as

```
[UIColor colorWithHue:32.0/360.0 saturation:0.88 brightness:0.97 alpha:1]
```

If I try to set the same color in storyboard, when running the App it is a slightly different colour to the one defined in code. If I drag the color to the palate then select a different color and select the palate one again, the HSB values are slightly different. It seems it is snapping to a different (RGB?) color in interface builder.

Comment: Using `colorWithHue` and not RGB web hex values: great choice.

Comment: In your code try logging the HSB values set by IB. If they are different file a bug: bugreporter.apple.com. I think I have also seen this issue.

Comment: same happened with me when selecting a UIView's bg color and setting same bg color for UITableView but different color. To achieve that i had make changes in color's alpha

Comment: Storyboard color logged: H:27.982594 S:0.899257 B:0.953253 I will report

Answer (score 229, accepted):

**Xcode 8+, iOS 10+**

I recently faced this problem and none of the posted answers did it. It turns out that with the release of iOS 10 SDK, the `UIColor` initializer `init(red:green:blue:alpha:)` now uses the extended sRGB range, so you have to set accordingly when configuring your color values on the Storyboard.

[image]

See Apple's documentation: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicolor/1621925-init

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Is it possible to apply this change globally across every Interface Builder (.xib and .storyboard) file without running some sort of manual script?

Comment: I think this gives a very good explanation about what you should do: https://lembergsolutions.com/blog/how-get-right-color-ios-detailed-instruction

Comment: Thank you so fucking muck, buddy! It works! You saved my evening

Answer (score 40):

I had the same issue.  I was seeing runtime RGB values of the colors from storyboards not matching UIColors created at runtime in code.  I was able to fix this in storyboards by setting the color to be "Generic RGB" (vs the default of sRGB) when configuring it.  Here is a screenshot of what I'm talking about in IB:

[image: IB Color config util]

Comment: I think I had tried that before, but it does seem to keep the correct values with Generic RGB now in Xcode 6.2, thanks

Comment: hey @Nick.  i am also on Xcode 6.2 and had that same problem you describe where it doesnt keep the values you set.  You have to play with it a little; there are conditions that cause it to reset (its a little buggy but i was able to work around them).

Comment: Please see @Camilo M answer if you're on ios 10 xcode 8

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 3**

In my case what was exactly accurate was ***Color LCD***:

[image]

I hope I've helped :-D

Comment: wow, they change the profiles a lot, I can confirm this works on XCode 9.

Answer (score 3):

With code, UIColor init(red:green:blue:alpha:) method return color object with sRGB color space;
With xib / StoryBoard, we need to select "sRGB IEC..." if we want to get same appearance as using code.

Such as:

```
UIColor.init(red: (20.0/255.0), green: (20.0/255.0), blue: (20.0/255.0), alpha: 1.0)
```

[xib / StoryBoard screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMDE1.png)

Actually，this problem has nothing to do with iOS 10.
After iOS 10, UIColor init uses "extended sRGB" instead of sRGB. And this will causes problems only when we use r g b values below 0.0 and above 1.0.

[iOS 10 UIColor related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38982769/ios-10-wide-color-do-i-need-to-be-concerned)

Answer (score 1):

Seems this is a bug. When logging the color set by IB in code, it has the values H:27.982594 S:0.899257 B:0.953253

I have filed a bug report to Apple: rdar://19744216

Thanks to Zaph

To log:

```
CGFloat cols[4];
[color getHue:&cols[0] saturation:&cols[1] brightness:&cols[2] alpha:&cols[3]];
NSLog(@"H:%f S:%f B:%f %f",cols[0]*360, cols[1], cols[2], cols[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following are 3 lines to achieve the desired navigation bar background color:

```
navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
```