# After updating device to iOS 11 3D model color changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, scenekit, uicolor

I am working with application using scene kit. And eveything is working fine until iOS 10.

I can see 3D model correct but after I updated my device to iOS 11 the colors of the model changed.

```
-(void)applyColor:(SCNNode*)node{
    NSArray *materials = node.geometry.materials;
    for (SCNMaterial *material in materials) {
        material.diffuse.contents = [UIColor purpalColor];
    }
}
```

iOS 9 and iOS 10: 
[image]

iOS 11: 
[image]

Comment: Please can you show some code as to how you are generating these images.

Comment: @Fogmeister I have added code in my original question. I am not creating any image from it but it's a 3D model and I am applying my custom color.

Comment: This has nothing to do with code. This is a result of the way colors are handled differently in iOS 11. You''ll need @mnuages or someone similarly knowledgeable about SceneKit and iOS to help with this.

Comment: @Confused thanks for sharing info

Comment: @Confused I have still not able to figure out how to solve this issue. is there any other place I have to check?

Comment: sorry to hear you are still struggling with this. I have added a bounty, I hope this helps find someone able to help you!

Comment: @DeveshM Maybe try also asking about this here: https://forums.developer.apple.com

Answer (score 6):

[According to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterial/1462589-diffuse), the default color is white for `meterial.diffuse.contents`.

> By default, the diffuse property’s contents object is a white color.

Not seeing your code, I do wonder about this line since this appears to be an obvious typo:

```
[UIColor purpalColor];
```

Presumably, it builds, so I assume it is a valid name.

Have you been able to verify that the color above is providing the desired value? Since it appears that iOS is expecting something, not  getting it, and sending back the default color here.

Comment: It doesn't look quite white to me, in the second image, more like a very bright pink.

Comment: @Confused I did go over it with color picker, and while it is not pure white, the values tend to align closely with white. The most common value I am seeing is 253,248,255. The G&B values are well out of range for a light pink IMO (color is subjective after all).

Comment: One thing I would like to add in my question is purpalColor is extension. Actual RGB color is (191,170,213) for but still it shows brighter in Scenekit 3D model. and for iOS 11 it's more brighter and it's changed. Do I need to add anything in my code?

Answer (score -2):

Just a thought, try using a non-custom color just to see if that gets you back on track. Possibly a clamping issue iOS 10 Wide Color?  Try searching this post:  [iOS 10 Wide Color: Do I need to be concerned?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38982769/). It specifically says UIKit and I didn't see anything specific to scenekit but again, just a thought.

Comment: just for your knowledge, "thoughts" should be mentioned in comments! ;)