# Hex color programmatically in swift differs with main storyboard

Tags: ios, swift

Whenever i try to put hex color code programatically in .swift file it always differ with from main.storyboard. Means i compare two buttons, one background button i put from code programmatically and second button background color i put from main.storyboard and both looks very different color

This is from Code

```
button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 57/255, blue: 68/255, alpha: 1.0)
```

Main.storyboard

```
button background color : #FF3944
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28367811/1187415.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User DeviceRGB to get exact same color while giving color using storyboard

[image: DeviceRGB]

Added simulator screen shot here.

[image: Smiluator]