# Different color shade of navigation bar in ViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, navigationbar, uicolor, bartintcolor

I have embedded my view controller in a navigation controller. I set the background color of the view in my view controller to a color (#ed1c24). And I want the navigation bar also be the same color.

But setting the tint color (same #ed1c24) in the attribute inspector of the navigation controller gives different shade in the view controller as shown in the image. What would be causing this issue?

[image: different shade in navigation bar]

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41928652/6818278

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along with setting **Translucent**, use the Style as **Black**. That would give the correct match with the colour in your view.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the right color the translucency is changing the visual for that color. Use this code to change it

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```